# A group satisfying $G=[G,G]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What kind of non-identity group $G$ satisfies $G=G'=[G,G]$? How is it related to a solvable or nilpotent group? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group

Comment: An example is $A_n$ for $n>4$ or ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ for $(n,q)\neq (2,2),(2,3)$. In both cases the argument is that certain generators ($3$-cycles in the alternating group case and elementary matrices in the special linear group case) are commutators in almost all cases.

Comment: At any rate, your question is quite vague and potentially too broad. Try to fix this.

Comment: Yeh...Perfect groups and they are not solvable. Thanks lulu and thanks for the examples Pedro.

Answer (score 2):

Such a group is called a perfect group. Note that any nonabelian simple group satisfies this because the commutator subgroup is normal. A nontrivial perfect group cannot be solvable since the series $G,G',[G',G']\ldots$ never terminates (and in particular does not terminate in a trivial group). For a sort of converse for finite groups, note that if a finite group is not solvable then eventually the series is constant, and that constant term is a perfect group.

As Jim Belk points out, not every perfect group is simple, and the smallest nonsimple perfect group is $\mathrm{SL}(2,5)$, which is of order $120$.

Comment: Excellent summary Matt! Thanks.

Comment: I would add that not every perfect group is simple.  According to $\textsf{GAP}$, the smallest such example is $\mathrm{SL}(2,5)$, which has order $120$.

Comment: @JimBelk edited as per your suggestion.